# How to specify search domain name of nginx resolver for proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, proxy, domain-name, resolve

Assuming my server is *www.mydomain.com*, on Nginx 1.0.6

I'm trying to proxy all request to http://www.mydomain.com/fetch to other hosts, the destination URL is specified as a GET parameter named "url".

For instance, when user requests either one:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/fetch?url=http://another-server.mydomain.com/foo/bar

http://www.mydomain.com/fetch?url=http://another-server/foo/bar
```

it should be proxyed to

```
http://another-server.mydomain.com/foo/bar
```

I'm using the following nginx config and it works fine only if the url paramter contains domain name, like **http://another-server.mydomain.com/...**; but fails on **http://another-server/...** on error:

```
another-server could not be resolved (3: Host not found)
```

nginx.conf is:

```
http {
...
# the DNS server
resolver 171.10.129.16;
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    root /path/to/site/root;

    location = /fetch {            
        proxy_pass $arg_url;
    }
}
```

Here, I'd like to resolve all URL without domain name as host name in *mydomain.com*, in /etc/resolv.conf, it's possible to specify default search domain name for the whole Linux system, but it doesn't affect nginx resolver:

```
search mydomain.com
```

Is it possible in Nginx? Or alternatively, how to "rewrite" the url parameter so that I can add the domain name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nginx performs its own DNS resolution and doesn't use the libc library, which is why `/etc/resolv.conf` doesn't have an effect. I can't find any option to specify a search domain, so rewriting the URL is your only option. Something like this should do the trick:

```
location /fetch {
    # Don't rewrite if we've already rewritten or the request already contains the full domain
    if ($arg_url !~ mydomain.com) {
        rewrite ^/fetch?url=http://([^/]+)(/?.*)$ /fetch?url=http://$1.mydomain.com$2;
    }
    proxy_pass $arg_url;
}
```

Comment: It looks the only working solution

Answer (score 0):

you can set domain as a variable，such as:

```
location /panel {                                                                    
#rewrite ^/panel(.*)$ http://10.252.97.140:31021/main/develop$1 permanent;    
#rewrite ^/panel(.*)$ $1 permanent;                                                                  
resolver 10.96.0.2;                                                                        
#resolver 10.252.97.139;                                                                   
set $dns_domain  ".dev-env.svc.cluster.local";                                                       
proxy_pass    http://panel-frontend$dns_domain/main/develop$1;               
#  proxy_pass http://panel-frontend.dev-env.svc.cluster.local/main/develop$1;
proxy_redirect    off;                                                                     
proxy_set_header  Host              $http_host;   # required for docker client's sake      
proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP         $remote_addr; # pass on real client's IP               
proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;                            
proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;                                               
proxy_read_timeout                  900;                                                   
}
```